# AngularJS: How to create new arrays from JSON response?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I have a function tied to the factory for my controller:

```
fac.GetDailyCountersList = function () {
    return $http.get('/Data/GetDailyCountersList')
}
```

Inside the controller, here's where the function is called:

```
$scope.DailyCounters = null;
DailyCounterService.GetDailyCountersList().then(function (d) {
    $scope.DailyCounters = d.data;
}, function (error) {
    alert('Error!');
});
```

Based on this, if I were to output the variable on the html page, this would show:

```
[{"Id":1,"MIDay":"16","MITime":"900","MICounter":0},
{"Id":2,"MIDay":"16","MITime":"915","MICounter":1},
{"Id":3,"MIDay":"16","MITime":"930","MICounter":0},
{"Id":4,"MIDay":"17","MITime":"945","MICounter":0},
{"Id":5,"MIDay":"17","MITime":"1000","MICounter":0},
{"Id":6,"MIDay":"17","MITime":"1015","MICounter":52},
{"Id":7,"MIDay":"18","MITime":"1030","MICounter":2},
{"Id":8,"MIDay":"18","MITime":"1045","MICounter":3},
{"Id":9,"MIDay":"18","MITime":"1100","MICounter":0}]
```

My question is how to take this data and create other arrays based on one of the properties of the Json data.

For example, how would I put arrays

```
{"Id":1,"MIDay":"16","MITime":"900","MICounter":0},
{"Id":2,"MIDay":"16","MITime":"915","MICounter":1},
{"Id":3,"MIDay":"16","MITime":"930","MICounter":0}
```

Into a new array "ArrayDay16"? And the rest into their respective arrays as well.

I was thinking about doing it this way:

```
var myArray = [];
if (d.data['MIDay'] == '16')
    myArray.push(d.data);
```

But this is incorrect/fails. Any ideas for an efficient solution?

Comment: Read up on [JavaScript's Array methods, especially `push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `filter` function to populate new arrays. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
//This will populate "someArray" with only the data that has MIDAY = 16
DailyCounterService.GetDailyCountersList().then(function (d) {
    $scope.someArray = d.data.filter(function(ele) {
        return ele.MIDAY === '16';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` function:

```
var daySixteen = data.filter(function (d) { return d.MIDay === "16"; });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the next:

```
d.data.foreach(function(item){
    if(item.MIDay == 16)
        myArray.push(d.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be efficient you should do this on the back end with constraint(s). It's not the browsers job.

Although, if you still want it to filter it on the front end you could use the filter-function with some lamdba expressions

```
var newList = oldList.filter(i => i["MIDay"] == "16");
```